# Slowly delete lots of subdirectories without impacting the server's performance

Tags: 20.04, performance, delete

I need to clean a directory which contains millions of subdirectories. I want to delete all subfolders that are older than 365 days. I tried this command:

`sudo nice -n 19 ionice -c 3 find . -type d -mtime +365 -exec  rm -rf '{}' +`

However, while this command runs, everything else on the machine gets very unresponsive.

Is there another way how to throttle the deletion of millions of subdirectories?

I run it on Ubuntu 20 with 256GB of memory.

Comment: The rm is not the problem. It is the find.

Comment: You may want to look at using something like [tmpreaper](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/tmpreaper.8.html) and starting with a very high number of days, then slowly work your way down to 365. [This blog post](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/10/tmpreaper-examples/) outlines some of the ways you can use the tool.

Comment: thanks @matigo, so you suggest to use something like `sudo nice -n 19 ionice -c 3 
 tmpreaper /home/mydirectory` ?